# KeyCloak identity broker without registration

Tags: keycloak, saml

I want to use keycloak as a identity broker.
However, it seems that keycloak needs to register user also in its database.
Is that possible to redirect directly to `redirect_uri` without registration after successful login with external identity provider?
Or is there any other service that I can use to integrate multiple SAML identity provider and return token?

Comment: Is this what you are looking https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_disabling_automatic_user_creation

Comment: @ravthiru It still need to register user.